# Azure Service Bus - unable to see the message

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, service-bus-explorer

The message is posted to the service bus from Java code and while checking in Azure portal -> service bus -> Possible to see the incoming and successful request.

I have been trying to see the Azure posted message using 'Service Bus Explorer'.

But not able to see the message though there is no issues in Azure portal -> service bus.

I am suspecting about configuration or access restriction. Since I am new to Azure Service Bus, not able to proceed how to process further.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Azure Portal, there is a menu to "peek messages", tried that? If you have any message consumers running for that queue/topic already, it would have got 'consumed'. BTW, you did not mention whether you sent to a queue or topic.

Comment: Actually , this message will be consumed by other application. In order to test that I used Service Explorer to view the message. The message is sent to topic.

Comment: If that consumer application has received the message and marked it as 'consumed', it will no longer appear in Azure portal. See about `receive mode` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#receive-modes)

Answer (score 2):

I do agree with @Anand Sowmithiran that,

> If that consumer application has received the message and marked it as 'consumed', it will no longer appear in Azure portal.

If the Consumer didn't do that then we can check messages as below process:
Firstly, open Service bus then click on Topic as below:

[image]

Then click on peek messages as below :

[image]

If the message is not sent/failed because of any reason you can check as below:

[image]

if the message is in receive mode then you should give session id as correctly as below:

[image]

After Clicking on Receive:

[image]

Comment: Thanks all for the details reply. But the actual issue is in Service Bus. Dropping off the service bus and recreation of the service bus worked.

Comment: I am glad that it worked out and my information might be helpful for similar issues.